# Using naive UI form components with inertiaJS

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, naiveui

I am using Naive UI in a Laravel InertiaJS app, and I need to set up forms and use Inertia forms to get real-time validation of forms.

I just don't know how to effectively use Naive UI components with InertiaJS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The way I did it was to use the NForm component with the NFormItem component and set the properties like:

```
<NForm>
    <n-space vertical>
      <NFormItem label="Username" size="large" :feedback="form.errors.name" :validation-status="form.errors.name ? 'error' : 'success'">
        <NInput v-model:value="form.name" />
      </NFormItem>

      <NFormItem label="Email" size="large" :feedback="form.errors.email" :validation-status="form.errors.email ? 'error' : 'success'">
        <NInput v-model:value="form.email" />
      </NFormItem>

      <NButton type="primary" :loading="form.processing" @click="submitForm">
        Submit
      </NButton>
    </n-space>
  </NForm>
```